# Debugging high-throughput station: why does a train stop when there is a path?

Tags: openttd

I'm puzzled with current pathfinder behavior when it comes to the entrance of the high-throughput station (and, correspondingly, to many paths to choose from).

In the following screenshot there is a train `Coal 0 #134` which stopped at one-way path signal:

[image]

Here is the same screenshot with the station hidden. Marked all busy and free tracks with red and yellow numbers. I can see that all tracks are in use at some point, so, there is nothing wrong with their exits.

[image]

If I un-pause/pause a few times then the train will select track #4:

[image]

It looks like that there are multiple options available for a pathfinder to choose from, but by some reason it picked #4 (where a train probably still hadn't fully left the station) forcing the train `Coal 0 #134` to stop. Such behavior obviously slows down the network.

Any ideas what is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to these bugs:

[[Bug]: Pathfinder prefers occupied plain track over free station track #9609](https://github.com/OpenTTD/OpenTTD/issues/9609)

[[Bug]: Trains do not use all available tracks #10467](https://github.com/OpenTTD/OpenTTD/issues/10467)

There are couple PRs attempting to fix it as well.

Comment: Bug #9609 is unrelated, but #10467 may stem from the same cause.